# Exchange 2019 Installation Fails at Mailbox Service

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016, windows-server-2019

I previously had Exchange 2010 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard) installed and two domain controllers 2008 and 2016. I have since removed the 2008 DC and 2010 Exchange Server and have a single 2016 controller.

I am currently in the process of installing Exchange 2019 (Microsoft Exchange Server 2019 Cumulative Update) on another box (Windows Server 2019) but the installation fails on step 8 of 12 (Mailbox role: Mailbox service).

**[image: I also get the below as part of the error message:]**

- ## No RetentionPolicy assigned to E-Discovery arbitration mailbox currently, we need to set it here.
- ## This can be remove after BUG(O15#2555914) is fixed.

I have a single Domain Controller (Windows Server 2016) and the Forest Functional Level set to Windows Server 2016

I am at a road block. Any suggestion to help me move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my research, it maybe related to the discovery system mailbox. Please check if it exists in "Users" OU.

If existing, please check the attribute “homeMDB” , ensure that it has a valid value same as other system mailbox.

Or run “Get-Mailbox -Filter { RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox" } | fl name, database” to see if it returns any error.

If anything wrong, you could try to delete this system database, and recreate it by running "Setup.exe /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms /PrepareAD", then re-run the setup wizard and check if issue persists.

You could refer to [this similar case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/da4cc01c-7bdf-421f-a39b-5809cc2ca441/setup-fails-on-step-8-exchange-server-2019?forum=Exch2019).